# Emoticon Table - IF Conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I am looking to implement a formula in Google Sheets, for example, if a cell has a value between 90-100, the cell next to the score will show a smiley face emoticon -

Is this something that can be done? I have created a table with scores to match up to emoticons but not sure how to implement or whether it's possible in Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to go here is a cell formula using IFS.

`=IFS(A2>=90,$O$2,A2>=80,$O$3,A2>=70,$O$4,A2>=60,$O$5,A2>=0,$O$6)`

Here's what the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]